# Dealing with NaN in matlab, simple tasks

Tags: matlab

I am working with data in matlab.

See code:

```
x = rand(10,1)
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]'
z = [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 2, 3, 4]'

ww = mean(z)-mean(y)
```

From this, `ww = Nan` how can I deal with these NaN values, I would like ww to be,

```
ww = 8.5-2.5
```

With the 8.5 coming from the last four numbers in y and the 2.5 the last four digits in z.

I am doing regressions in MATLAB with time series data, for certain series there is missing data NaNs at the start of the series. I am wondering how to deal with them and the above example is a Complete Minimal example.

Edit:

For a slightly more complicated example, trying to use the archtest

```
clear;
%data
data = xlsread('RETURNS.xlsx',2);

for jj = 2:51
    for ii = 1:12
        residuals = data(:,jj) - mean(data(:,jj));
        h(jj,ii) = archtest(residuals,'Lags',ii);
    end
end
```

Where there are NaNs in some of the columns.

Comment: Simple IF could do the thing ... calculate mean without using "mean". Use long way :)

Comment: You can just use `x(~isnan(x))` to get the non-NaN values from an array.

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks, yes, I know, but then how do I get the last four from y

Comment: `x = x(~isnan(x)); x(end-3:end);`

Comment: @Wolfie yes that works for this specific example, but lets say I have 200 time series!!

Comment: how can the isnan work for the interaction between two series? One series has NaNs one doesn't

Comment: `idx = ~isnan(z); y = y(idx); z = z(idx);` The function `isnan` returns a Boolean array, use it however you like.

Comment: thanks @Wolfie !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

**Answer for the original question:**

You can tell the `mean` function and several others to disregard `NaN` values by providing the flag `omitnan`:

```
 y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]'
 z = [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 2, 3, 4]'

 ww = mean(z,'omitnan')-mean(y,'omitnan')
```

Several other functions like `max`, `min`, `sum`, `prod`, etc. also accept this flag.

And as an aside, if you are working with time series data, you may want to check out whether you can use `timetable`.  It may simplify some of your workflows.

**Answer for the updated question**:

I'm not sure what `archtest` does, as it's not in my area of expertise, but if it's fine for your workflow to simply remove NaNs, then you can use `rmmissing` as a pre-processing step to remove them.  I'm not sure if this will affect the meaning of the `Lags`, however, since you are removing indices.  I think in that case you'll have to decide what's appropriate to do for your data.  If you simply want to replace the NaNs with some other value (like 0), you can use `fillmissing` to do that.

Comment: Although this works for the above question, my example was too simplistic. How would this work day for the edit...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am not sure my question has been entirely understood. I am a student and used to using Eviews, say I had missing data in eviews and I want to regress x on y, and y had 1000 data points and x only has 500, it would just use 500, for the entire regression. If I had another dataset z with 1000 it would use 1000 if I regressed z on y. I am just struggling with simples things like this when using MATLAB. Thanks four your help again!